# Работа со списком адресов файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список `next` содержит адреса файлов. Их может быть неизвестное количество при попытке `os.remove(next)` выходит:

> TypeError: remove: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list

как удалить те файлы, которые находятся в списке?

Comment: Не лучшая идея называть список (любую переменную) именем `next`, т.к. существует стандартная функция с таким именем

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы передаёте в функцию весь список, а нужно передавать путь к файлу. Так можно удалить все файлы по путям из списка:

```
for file in next: # проходим по списку
    os.remove(file) # передаём очередной путь в функцию
```